# The price book entry is in a different price book than the one assigned to the Work Order,

Tags: apex, trigger, pricebook, work-order

hi i'm trying to test a class with price book entry and work order and Product Consumed but i got this error when i insert a product consumed: **FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, The price book entry is in a different price book than the one assigned to the Work Order, or Work Order has no price book assigned.: [PricebookEntryId]**. Can someone help me?

```
@TestSetup
static void makeData(){
    User u = DataFactory.createUSer('test@ttttt.test');
    insert u;

    Account acc = DataFactory.createAccount('Account 1', 'test', 'SAGENumber1');
    insert acc;

    Contact cont = DataFactory.createContact('contact 1', acc.Id);
    insert cont;

    Case cas = DataFactory.createCase(cont.Id);
    insert cas;

    List<Product2> products = DataFactory.createProducts(2);
    insert products;

    Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
    Pricebook2 priceBook2 = DataFactory.createPricebook();
    insert priceBook2;

    PriceBookEntry pbe1 = DataFactory.constructPricebookEntries(products[0], pricebookId, 100);
    insert pbe1;

    PriceBookEntry pbe2 = DataFactory.constructPricebookEntries(products[0], priceBook2.Id, 100);
    insert pbe2;


    List<Opportunity> opps = DataFactory.createOpportunity(acc.Id, priceBook2.Id, 1);
    insert opps;

    Quote quote = DataFactory.createQuote(acc.Id, 'quote 1','FIHT', cont.Id, opps[0].Id, priceBook2.Id);
    insert quote;

    QuoteLineItem ql = DataFactory.createQuoteLineItem(products[0].Id, 2, 50, quote.Id, pbe2.Id);
    insert ql;

    WorkOrder wo = DataFactory.createWorkOrder(acc.Id, cas.Id, cont.Id, quote.Id, priceBook2.Id, CMN_UTILS.NONE);
    insert wo;
    System.debug('### wo.Pricebook2Id '+ wo.Pricebook2Id);
    
    ProductConsumed pc = DataFactory.createProductConsumed(wo.Id, pbe2.Id, 12, /*10,*/ 1, CMN_UTILS.LYON);
    insert pc;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Your example isn't reproducible - it doesn't show `DataFactory` code.